# Howto to start docker daemon under fedora, so that it is bound to tcp port

Tags: docker

I am trying to start the docker daemon under fedora, so that I can connect to it using localhost:2375. So I added a file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/localport.conf
```

and added:

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=\"-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375\""
```

Now I restart the daemon (or even the whole system). But I cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:2375.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit

```
/etc/sysconfig/docker
```

And add (or edit if it already exists):

```
OPTIONS='-H=127.0.0.1:2375'
```